# Convert emoji to send data to JSON and receive in same manner

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

'm encoding the emoji_icon using following code and sending data to web using JSON..

```
NSString *emoji_str=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[text UTF8String]];
NSData *new_data=[emoji_str dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *emoji=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:new_data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and decoding using following code..

```
NSString *emo_str=[[comments  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"comment"]; //this string data is coming from web
const char *jsON_responce= [emo_str UTF8String];
NSData *data_1=[NSData dataWithBytes:jsON_responce length:strlen(jsON_responce)];
NSString *text_Str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data_1 encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

but instead of decoding in emoji the output is something like this "ud83dude1c".

I also want to ask this, issue is raised from my side or is it database issue???
please help in solving the following issue.
thanks

Comment: Is `emoji_icon` image?

Comment: No, i am using emotions from iPhone emoji keyboard..